# SVG object scaling in Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css, svg, android-browser

I'm having this problem with a website we're building.

http://swaegersverzekeringen.e-staging.be

At the top left we have the company logo, which is an SVG image. (fyi : IE lte 9 a png gets loaded)

The SVG scales perfectly if I give the object tag holding the svg another width and height at different breakpoints. Now apparently, Android browser likes to do his own thing and doesn't scale the svg at all.

I can see that the object tag IS given the proper width, but the svg is displaying at full size and gets cropped because the object container is 100px wide.

I've been googling about this for an hour now, so I decided to ask around here what might be the solution.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you're using an **object** instead of an **img** tag?
You could deliver IE9 a .png as well and use **img** for browsers that support it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add style="max-height: 100%" in the actual SVG file. You can use the  tag in your markup, but using  tag is better.

[image: Include the max-height]